# Libgdx Accelerometer not working?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, accelerometer, gyroscope

for some reason the block is not moving when I tilt the screen, and I don't know what's wrong. Just to clarify, I set the cfg.accelerometer to true, but the cfg.compass to false. Here's the source code-

```
public void update() 
{

    x += velX;
    y += velY;

    //movement

    //left
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT))
    {
        velX = -speed;
    }

    //right
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT))
    {
        velX = speed;
    }

    //up
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP))
    {
        velY = -speed;
    }

    //down
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN))
    {
        velY = speed;
    }

    if (Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Accelerometer))
    {
        velX = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
        velY = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
    }

    //stop
    if (!Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT) && !Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT))
    {
        velX = 0;
    }

    if (!Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP) && !Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN))
    {
        velY = 0;
    }

    //collision with edges of screen
    if (x <= 0)
    {
        x = 0;
    }

    if (x >= 1920 - width)
    {
        x = 1920 - width;
    }

    if (y <= 0)
    {
        y = 0;
    }

    if (y >= 1080 - height)
    {
        y = 1080 - height;
    }

    long recoveryElapsed = (System.nanoTime() - recoveryTimer)/1000000;
    if (recoveryElapsed > 2000)
    {
        recovering = false;
        recoveryTimer = 0;
    }

    System.out.println(lives+ " lives, recovering, "+recovering);

}
```

Help would be much appreciated, thanks. There are no tutorials that I have found with a working example shown, so I don't really know if what I am doing is correct, but I can't see anything wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the Accel values, and then if the keys are not pressed you are setting them to 0 again. Do it like this:

```
//stop
if (!Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT) && !Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT))
{
    velX = 0;
}

if (!Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP) && !Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN))
{
    velY = 0;
}

if (Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Accelerometer))
{
    velX = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
    velY = Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY();
}
```